# Fastest way to decide if string contains only allowed values?

Tags: java

I'm trying to determine what is the *fastest* way to implement this code:

```
Pattern ID_REGEX = Pattern.compile( "[A-Za-z0-9_\\-.]+" );
boolean match = ID_REGEX.matcher( id ).matches();
if ( !match ) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Disallowed character in ID");
```

Given that the ID_REGEX is constant, I would assume something like a BitSet or an array of permitted values is the fastest way to implement this, maybe even just a huge if statement.

Note that the search is for A-Za-z, *not* Character.isLetter.

Additional kudos for an OSS implementation

Comment: I don't understand. You mean without the regular expression in java?

Comment: Why don't you just write a test to measure it ?

Comment: Is this *actually* performance critical? Does the code you've already got not work fast *enough*?

Comment: I feel this is relevant: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: I don't feel its fair to downvote. While this kind of optimization can be very pointless, there are some occasions where it's valid, and if the poster wants to ask the question, who are we to say otherwise.

Comment: It is probably 10x faster to implement this as a for loop than a regex, and I could of course implement all of the variations to find the answer to this question. I suppose one always has to suffer through a cacophony of "dont micro-optimize" when asking this kind of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My fast but unclear solution

```
// encapsulate this into a class and do once; perhaps use a static initializer
boolean[] allowed = new boolean[256]; // default false
allowed[32] = true;
allowed['a'] = true;
// fill all allowed characters
allowed['Z'] = true;

// the check
for (int n=0,len=str.length(); n<len; n++) {
  char ch = str.charAt(n);
  if (ch>255 || !allowed[ch]) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

Some additional casts may be needed, but I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: Change the check `ch>256` to `ch>255`to avoid nasty surprises when ch is 256.

Comment: I did some tests and boolean array seems to be about 30% faster than if test, which again is 10x the speed of regex

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could iterate through string, get code of character, compare with ASCII table codes. This way at each character you have 3 `between` comparisons(for a-z, A-Z, 0-9) and 6 usual integer comparisons for other chars. I think it will be fastest. You could also try multithreading approach, in which you do basically the same, but divide problem into several parts before starting and make checks concurrently.
Edit(after @krosenvold comment): multithreading approach is suitable only for very big strings, because creating threads has its own price.

Comment: I think you'd need some pretty huge strings for a multi-threading approach to get anywhere, I've actually never ever been able to get parallelize operations at this granularity, it seldom works well for such small operations, most of the computation will be within cpu L1 cache for such an algorithm, which is where 1-core shines